# A working query returning null when run through laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to use a simple query with laravel but its not returning any data. but when I run same query in phpmyadmin it returns 3 rows.

This is code in laravel.

```
 $pages = DB::table('static_pages')
     ->where('slug','=','(select slug from static_pages where id='.$id.')')
         ->get();
```

this is the query it makes.

```
  select * from `static_pages` where `slug` = (select slug from static_pages where id=2)
```

Can you tell me what could be the reason?

Comment: make as DB:row in where clause

Comment: Do you know about model

Comment: @AjayKumar I am new to laravel. I have worked in CI earlier. in CI it was very easy to use models. but here I was only able to make a class and there i put the table name. using just like this : CLASS::where()->get();

Comment: you can make model using artisan command like `php artisan make:model StaticPage` and it will be in `app\StaticPage` linked to `static_pages` table the you can access it like `StaticPage::where(...)->get()` and it's very easy to use instead of using `DB`

Comment: but why you are trying to get a page by its slug that you are getting it by its id
why not you get the page by its id directly??!!
slug and id are unique, so you can get the page by id also??

Comment: @HassanAliSalem I am going to change the name slug to group. So here I have the ID of current page. but I need other pages from this page's group too that's why I am using this . A group can have more than 1 page.

Comment: ah ok
so thats it
but for info there is something called models and relations in laravel
so you dont have to do these queries 
you have model named Page and another one named Group
Page belongs to group as pages
so if you have group object you can do $group->pages
and also if you have page object that belongs to group
you can do $page->group
and so on
read about laravel models and relations

Comment: @HassanAliSalem thanks for the info

Answer (score 3):

If what you refer to is the relationship between two tables then you might want to look at Laravel Model Relationship, however if you want to retrieve all records having the same slug *of* the `record with id = 2` then you can also do it without using two DB:raw:

```
DB::table('static_pages')->where('slug', function ($query) {
        return $query->from('static_pages')->where( 'id', '2')->select('slug');
    })->get();
```

If you want to inspect the sql query it generates then use `toSql()` instead of `->get()`

One evil thing to anticipate is if your inner query returns a collections of values then your comparison might become questionable. However since the field you use to make the query is unique, then this should not be a problem.

Hope this is useful.

Answer (score 1):

It worked by changing from this

```
 $pages = DB::table('static_pages')->where('slug','=','(select slug from static_pages where id='.$id.')')->get();
```

to this

```
$pages = DB::table('static_pages')->where('slug','=',DB::table('static_pages')->where('id','=',$id)->pluck('slug'))->get();
```

thanks to jishad

Comment: or as simple as: 
 $pages = DB::table('static_pages')->where('slug','=',DB::raw('(select slug from static_pages where id='.$id.')'))->get();
so just ad raw to your code

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
DB::table('static_pages')->whereRaw("`slug` = (select slug from static_pages where id=2)")->get();
```

hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
 $pages = DB::table('static_pages')->where('slug','=',DB::raw('(select slug from static_pages where id='.$id.')'))->get();
```